# Is the mass of a mole identical for different elements?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

For example, if I have 2 moles of iron and 2 moles of copper, do I have an equal mass of each?

Comment: Have you tried answering this yourself? Please tell us where you got stuck by [edit]ing.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can calculate this on your own! (I'll just point you in the right direction)

To calculate the mass of the two you'll have to multiply their molar mases by the amount of mols (in this case 2 mols). At the end compare the two mases!

(The molar mass is equal to the relative atomic mass, but only for monoatomic elements)